# Thymeleaf href to controller : Could not parse as expression

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Thymleaf href inside a loop.

```
<th:block th:each="study : ${studyList}">
                <tr>
                    <td th:text="${study.patient.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${study.status}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${study.description}"></td>
                    <td><a th:href="@{/updateStudy/{studyId} (studyId=${study.id})}>"</a>Update</td>
                </tr>
</th:block>
```

And my controller definition is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateStudy/{studyId}")
    public void updateStudy(@RequestParam("studyId") long studyId
                                             ) {
....
}
```

The page is not rendering as I am getting parsing exception:

> Could not parse as expression: "@{/updateStudy/{studyId}
>   (studyId=${study.id})}>"

Also in the html page it is complianing : Undefined attribute name ((studyId).

What I am missing here ? Kindly help.

**UPDATE**:

Apparently the expression should have been

```
<td><a th:href="@{/updateStudy/{studyId} (studyId=${study.id})}" >Update</a></td>
```

Now at least the parsing error is resolved. But I am getting this:

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required long parameter 'studyId' is not present

Hopefully it is not related to the href expression.

**SOLVED**

Just to complete the answer, I have changed the controller definition to

```
@GetMapping("/updateStudy/{studyId}")
    public String updateSchedulePage(@PathVariable Long studyId, Model model) {
..}
```

And now everything works fine.

Comment: :D. updated both question & answer at same time

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<td><a th:href="@{/updateStudy/${study.id}}" >Update</a></td>
```

Here is another problem in controller:

```
@RequestParam will be `@PathVariable `
```

Change to it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateStudy/{studyId}")
public void updateStudy(@PathVariable ("studyId") long studyId
                                         ) {
```

....
}

Comment: Hi sajib, although this seems obvious, but it does not work with Thymeleaf. Kindly check my **UPDATE** in the question, I have figured out the expression. Also posting the controller in a moment.

Comment: ok . now there is problem in controller. see i updated answer